# How to minimize and restore process with lots of instances?

Tags: vb.net, instance, restore, minimize

I have a code here but on button click some instances doesn't really go minimized or restored. I tried everything I could but no luck for me.

```
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32.dll" ( _
ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
ByVal nCmdShow As Show_Window _
) As Boolean

Private Enum Show_Window As Integer
    Hide = 0
    ShowNormal = 1
    ShowMinimized = 2
    ShowMaximized = 3
    Maximize = 3
    ShowNormalNoActivate = 4
    Show = 5
    Minimize = 6
    ShowMinNoActivate = 7
    ShowNoActivate = 8
    Restore = 9
    ShowDefault = 10
    ForceMinimized = 11
End Enum

Private Sub MinimizeAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MinimizeAllToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim p() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("GameServer")
    Dim p1() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("AccountServer")
    Dim p2() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("GateServer")
    Dim p3() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("GroupServer")
    Dim p4() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("TradeServer")
    Dim p5() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("FilterServer")
    If MinimizeAllToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Minimize All" Then
        For Each pr As Process In p
            ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, Show_Window.ForceMinimized)
        Next pr
        For Each pr As Process In p1
            ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, Show_Window.ForceMinimized)
        Next pr
        For Each pr As Process In p2
            ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, Show_Window.ForceMinimized)
        Next pr
        For Each pr As Process In p3
            ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, Show_Window.ForceMinimized)
        Next pr
        For Each pr As Process In p4
            ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, Show_Window.ForceMinimized)
        Next pr
        For Each pr As Process In p5
            ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, Show_Window.ForceMinimized)
        Next pr
        MinimizeAllToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Restore All"
    Else
        For Each pr As Process In p
            ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, Show_Window.Restore)
        Next pr
        For Each pr As Process In p1
            ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, Show_Window.Restore)
        Next pr
        For Each pr As Process In p2
            ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, Show_Window.Restore)
        Next pr
        For Each pr As Process In p3
            ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, Show_Window.Restore)
        Next pr
        For Each pr As Process In p4
            ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, Show_Window.Restore)
        Next pr
        For Each pr As Process In p5
            ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, Show_Window.Restore)
        Next pr
        MinimizeAllToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Minimize All"
    End If
End Sub
```

What could be wrong? Or maybe someone can share your code on how to minimize and restore process with lots of instances. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you include some more details about what's going wrong?  And is it possible for you to post working code that will compile on its own?  That will help us diagnose.

Comment: Hello @kdbanman, this code is working and its compiling without error. The problem is, whenever i hit that button, sometimes some instance dont go minimize and sometimes dont go restore.

Answer (score 2):

Really not sure where the problem might be, but you could reduce the code significantly using something like this:

```
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32.dll" (
    ByVal hWnd As IntPtr,
    ByVal nCmdShow As Show_Window
    ) As Boolean

Private Enum Show_Window As Integer
    Hide = 0
    ShowNormal = 1
    ShowMinimized = 2
    ShowMaximized = 3
    Maximize = 3
    ShowNormalNoActivate = 4
    Show = 5
    Minimize = 6
    ShowMinNoActivate = 7
    ShowNoActivate = 8
    Restore = 9
    ShowDefault = 10
    ForceMinimized = 11
End Enum

Private Sub MinimizeAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MinimizeAllToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim processes() As String = {"GameServer", "AccountServer", "GateServer", "GroupServer", "TradeServer", "FilterServer"}
    Dim cmd As Show_Window = If(MinimizeAllToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Minimize All", Show_Window.Minimize, Show_Window.Restore)
    For Each processName As String In processes
        For Each pr As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)
            ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, cmd)
        Next
    Next
    MinimizeAllToolStripMenuItem.Text = If(MinimizeAllToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Restore All", "Minimize All", "Restore All")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for optimizing, but I'm not so sure as well where the programs could be. Just for an idea, I used your code before which I used on this code as well that's holding those servers.
http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28736752/VB-net-Auto-Restart-Application.html